# Событие по зажатию на тачскрине

Tags: javascript, mobile-web, touch

Есть такой вот код, так он работает по событию мыши и все хорошо.
Но на мобильных устройствах не работает, нужно событие по зажатию или что-то похожие не могу найти решение. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```js
document.getElementById('slide').onmousemove = function (event){
 var x = event.offsetX;//относительно родителя!
 document.getElementById('two').style.width = x + 'px';
}
```

```css
#slide {
 width: 375px;
 height: 400px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#one, #two {
 width: 375px;
 height: 400px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#one {
 background: green;
}
#two {
 width: 150px;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div id="slide">
  <div id="one">
  </div>
  <div id="two">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: А как вы себе представляете, как это должно на мобильном работать?

Comment: когда ведешь пальцем влево или вправо, происходит тоже самое когда мышью ведешь

Comment: Ну вот значит, гуглите событие проведением пальцем. Затем делайте то же самое, как и при движении мыши.